# Jquery .click function, change behaviour for particular id

Tags: jquery, css

So I have this function

```
    $('#wrapper').click(function () {
        hideDropDown();
        checkForPiehtcFix();
        hideSearch();
    });
```

The #wrapper contains all my content. So whenever I click anywhere I am hiding my search div.

```
   function hideSearch() {
        isDropSearch = false;
        $('#mn_search').css({ 'background-position': '0 0' });
        $('#dd_search').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    }
```

The issue is that when the user clicks on my search i.e. div #dd_search I don't want to hide search because the user never gets to enter a search because when they click on it it closes.

So I am looking to adding a clause within #wrapper click to check if they clicked within #dd_search and if they did then I don't want to call hideSearch();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**One way is:**

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', ':not(#dd_search)'(function () {
    ...
});
```

**Second way is:**

```
$('#wrapper').click(function (e) {
    if (e.target.id == 'dd_search' || $(e.target).find('#dd_search').length)
        return false;
    ...
    ...
});
```

**Third way is:**

```
$('#wrapper').click(function () {
    ...
});

$('#dd_search').click(function(){
    return false; // stops the bubbling.
});
```

Comment: Still closes everytime how can I find out what the id of the area jquery thinks I am clicking on so I can double check it is dd_search

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#wrapper").click(function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).is("#dd_search") {
      //special handling when dd_search is clicked
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#wrapper').click(function () {
    hideDropDown();
    checkForPiehtcFix();
    if( !$(this).is('#dd_search') ) {
        hideSearch();
    }
});
```

Comment: How could I find out what the id !($this).is because its not working with dd_search even though that is the area I am clicking in

Comment: @StevieB `console.log(this.id);`

Comment: ah there is the problem I think it's #wrapper even when I click on the Search area which is #dd_search

Answer (score 0):

```
   $('#wrapper>*').not('#dd_search').click(function () {
      hideDropDown();
      checkForPiehtcFix();
      hideSearch();
    });
```

Fires if any child of the wrapper except the dd_search is clicked.

Comment: Still closes every time eventhough I am click the area I am clicking is within dd_search which is within #wrapper

Comment: I tested this with some inner markup (p, div) in a simple page here: http://jsfiddle.net/9rwbf/ likely some complexity in your markup that is inforseen.